# How to append rows as new columns of a dataframe R

Tags: r

Im not sure if this is possible, I have a large dataframe which I'm trying to manipulate into a format to work with. Essentially what I want is any element in column 1 which contains text is to be appended to the end of the previous row which have an id number in column 1. What makes this complicated is that there can be numerous text elements between numerical IDs.

```
Example  
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1234","2345", "3456", "text1", "text2"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6", "data7"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

It appears like so

```
1234 data1  
text1 data2  
2345 data3  
text1  data4  
text2 data5  
3456 data6  
text1  data7
```

What I want is

```
1234 data1 text1 data2  
2345 data3 text1 data4 text2 data5  
3456 data6 text1 data7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility involving `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(grp = cumsum(!grepl("text", V1, fixed = TRUE))) %>%
 gather(var, val, -grp) %>%
 group_by(grp) %>%
 mutate(var = paste0("V", row_number())) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 select(-grp)

  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1234  text1 data1 data2 <NA>  <NA> 
2 2345  text1 text2 data3 data4 data5
3 3456  text1 data6 data7 <NA>  <NA>
```

Or if you want to match your desired output exactly:

```
df %>%
 group_by(grp = cumsum(!grepl("text", V1, fixed = TRUE))) %>%
 mutate(grp2 = row_number()) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 gather(var, val, -c(grp, grp2)) %>%
 arrange(grp, grp2) %>%
 group_by(grp) %>%
 mutate(var = paste0("V", row_number())) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp2) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 select(-grp)

  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1234  data1 text1 data2 <NA>  <NA> 
2 2345  data3 text1 data4 text2 data5
3 3456  data6 text1 data7 <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks a mill.

Comment: Just in case anyone is looking for something similar but with more text options substitute the second line for the following: `group_by(grp = cumsum(!grepl("text|words|sound", V1))) %>%`